# Convergence in distribution of the sum of two random sequences

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence

Let $x_n, y_n$ be sequences of zero mean random variables, not necessarily i.i.d. 
Suppose that there are finite $\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2$ such that
$$x_n\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma_1^2), $$ and
$$y_n\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma_2^2). $$
Can I say that $x_n+y_n{\to} N(0,\sigma^2)$ for some finite $\sigma^2$?

I know that I can't describe $\sigma_2$, but the limiting distribution of $x_n+y_n$ is still normally distributed?

Comment: No.  A similar question is if $X$ and $Y$ are individually Gaussian $N(0,1)$, is it true that $X+Y$ is Gaussian? (no).  This is the same question as yours if we define $X_n=X$ and $Y_n=Y$ for all $n$.

Comment: You can make $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $$Y=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} X & \mbox{ if $|X|<1$} \\ -X & \mbox{ if $|X|\geq 1$} \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/467608/119261.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ have $N(0,1)$ distribution, $Y=X$ if $|X| <1$ and $-X$ if $|X| \geq 1$. Take $X_n=X$ for all $n$ and $Y_n=Y$ for all $n$. This gives  a counter-example.